# CreateProcess returns true but does not execute with regedit

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, registry, regedit

I am trying to dump a portion of the windows registry in a .txt file using the `CreateProcess` function. The code is along the lines of

```
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
STARTUPINFO si;
ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

CString cmdLine = "\"C:\\WINDOWS\\regedit.exe\" /e \"c:\\dump\\TestReg.txt\" 
                   \"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\MYSOFT\\\"";
LPSTR pCmdLine = (LPSTR)(const char*)cmdLine;
BOOL oc = CreateProcess(NULL, pCmdLine, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
if(oc == TRUE)
{
    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, 1000); 
    GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess, &exitCode);
    if(exitCode != 0) ret = -1;
}
```

**What I know**

- The `CreateProcess` returns `TRUE` and the last blocks executes
- The process waits for the end and exits normally
- However no file is produced at the end
- The command line string works fine in command line, even when it operates from the same directory where the program is operating.
- I have found something that is potentially [useful](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/9f1ee778-0713-442f-93a8-338d5f572f81/createprocess-doesnt-work-for-one-application-while-it-does-for-another-no?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues) where someone had basically the same problem. In the end it resulted in a dependency clash but the link does not explain very well how it was detected or fixed.

Comment: Regedit.exe is special, it is a single-instance app.  Easy to see, just try to start it twice and note that you'll only get one instance on your desktop.  Also some odds that it its silent UAC elevation plays a role.  So you are waiting only for your instance to quit but it is actually another instance that gets the job done.  Later, after you try to find the file back.  Or not at all, I didn't try it.  Well, hard to deal with so don't do this.  Consider using reg.exe instead, /export option.

Comment: I think Hans is likely onto something with the UAC comment.  Are you running your program as Administrator?